# Rails show rgb color string as color swatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, colors, ruby-on-rails-4, rgb, rmagick

Im using RMagick to take the average color of an image a user uploads. and I've got it down to displaying as RGB format. Now I'd like to take that RGB string and display it as a color swatch on the page...any idea on how to accomplish this?

```
{:r=>155, :g=>132, :b=>118}
```

Comment: I'm going to convert this to hexadecimal then just style it with front end code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# controller
@image = Magick::Image.read(@design.photo.path).first
average_color = # your magick method to return the average color
# so average is like " {:r=>155, :g=>132, :b=>118} "
@average_color_string = "##{average_color.values.map{|v| v.to_s(16) }.join}"

#view
Average color: <%= @average_color_string %>
```

should display something like this:

> Average color: #9b8476

The `.to_s(16)` converts the Integer into a 16-based string, also known as **Hexadecimal**.

Comment: Thanks again @MrYoshij. you've been a tremendous help today

Comment: You're welcome @Justin, it's not a busy day at work today.. ahah!

Comment: haha good thing because it allowed me to accomplish a task i've been putting off for a few weeks! Again, thanks a ton.