# Using rgmagick and getting error for file not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rmagick

Using rmagick to find the colors of an image..

```
img = Magick::Image.read("#{Rails.root}/public#{@design.photo.url(:profile)}").first
```

Here is the error

```
unable to open image `/tmt/public/system/designs/photos/000/000/005/profile/5.jpg?1380037883': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2646
```

The file is pointing to the exact location of the image, maybe the extension (?1380037883) is throwing it off but i can't seem to solve the problem. Do y'all know what's going on? Maybe you've seen a similar problem using rgmagick...heres my gemfile

```
gem 'rmagick', :require => 'RMagick'
```

If i point to an image in my app/assets/images directory it works perfectly...it's just when im using variables to find the image a user uploads that is has this error...

for instance this works perfectly

```
img = Magick::Image.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/ruby.png").first
```

Comment: just use `img = Magick::Image.read @design.photo.path(:profile)` to return the **full path** of the file

Comment: That doesn't return anything

Comment: `@design.photo.url(:profile)` is Paperclip code, right? If yes then `@design.photo.path` should return the full path of the file.

Comment: yep paperclip..good call....What finally worked was this

`img = Magick::Image.read(@design.photo.path).first`

Comment: want to take a stab at 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227763/rails-show-rgb-color-string-as-color-swatch

Comment: You might want to accept my answer for the next users (and I could finally pass over 10k reputation!!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `.path` method instead of `.url`:

- `.url` returns the **relative path** of the file
- `.path` returns the **absolute path** of the file

In your case:

```
img = Magick::Image.read( @design.photo.path ).first
```